# Not able to delete object while search

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table view with two sections,selected items are in section 0 and all list of items are in section 1. and a search bar for searching items in table view. search functionality is working fine. inserting and deleting functionality is also working fine in normal mode. but if i am deleting object while searching it gets crash at

```
[searcheddataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Alllist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ajmeri gate",@"Chawri bazar",@"Delhi Cant",@"VidhanSabha",@"Dhaula Kuan",@"Nehru Nagar", nil];

    selectedlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [aTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

    searcheddataArray = Alllist;

}



-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section==0)
    {
        NSUInteger count = [self.selectedlist count];
        if(self.editing) count++;
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        return [searcheddataArray count];
    }

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Selected List";
    if(section == 1)
        return @"All List";
    else
        return nil;
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {

        cell.textLabel.text = [selectedlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {

        cell.textLabel.text=[searcheddataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    return cell;
}




- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        [searcheddataArray insertObject:[selectedlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:[searcheddataArray count]];

        [self.selectedlist removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [aTableView reloadData];
    }

    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {

        [self.selectedlist insertObject:[searcheddataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:[self.selectedlist count]];


            [searcheddataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [aTableView reloadData];
    }
}



- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.aSearchbar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    [aTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [self.aSearchbar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    searchBar.text=@"";
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length>0)
    {
        searchText = [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"its pincode");

        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
        searcheddataArray= [Alllist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

        [aTableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        searcheddataArray=Alllist;
        [aTableView reloadData];
    }
}


- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.aSearchbar resignFirstResponder];
}



- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.aSearchbar resignFirstResponder];
    searcheddataArray=Alllist;

    [self.aTableView reloadData];
}



@end
```

I must be missing something but I can't figure out where. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2016-01-07 13:42:23.381 tableselecting[5828:70309] its pincode
2016-01-07 13:42:24.537 tableselecting[5828:70309] -[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8478594ca0
2016-01-07 13:42:24.540 tableselecting[5828:70309] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8478594ca0'

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //your code
}

While inserting or deleting the array objects in the above method you have to add tableview beginUpdate and tableview endUpdate methods.

See the below links, It may helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260279/what-is-the-benefit-of-calling-beginupdates-endupdates-for-a-uitableview-as-oppo
```

Comment: hi @user2742856  i did  but getting error - 
 invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0)

Answer (score 0):

The exception message:

```
[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]:
```

Indicates you have an (*immutable*) `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`.

I cannot see the reason why from the code you posted, however at some point you have assigned the wrong type of object to an instance variable.

Comment: That is why i posted the code . because all arrays are mutable and i am getting this error.

Comment: @PriyantaSingh I can only tell you that exceptions are never wrong, but developers are frequently wrong.  You have assigned an `NSArray` at some point.  Review all your code.

Comment: Yes you are right . but again i reviewed my code  and didn't found any NSArray i have assigned.

Comment: I am not getting this error if i am deleting before search. but while search i am getting this error.

Comment: @PriyantaSingh That's a clue.  Your search is causing the `NSArray` to be set.

Comment: ok .  @trojanfoe  thank a lot helping me .. let me check again.