# Do I have to call begin/endUpdates method when a new row is inserted into the tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uitableview

1. **Description:**

   A table view with 3 rows is created when the app is started. A add button in the navigation bar will add a new row into the table view if tapped. The core process behind the add row action is the method `func insertRows(at:, with:)`.

   [Apple documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates) and many stack-overflow answers (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift)) suggest that put any method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view between function `beginUpdates()` and `endUpates()`.

   I removed the `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`; it turns out the app works just fine without them.
2. **Question:**

   What are the benefits of adding `beginUpdates()` & `endUpdates()`?
3. **Why I ask this question:**

   The function `func insertRows(at:, with:)` is calling the delegate function `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:) -> UITableViewCell` to create a new cell via `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:) -> UITableViewCell`, this is the same procedural the `tableView` creates the 3 default rows when the app started, but, there is no such a `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` there. So why do I need to add this procedure later when I add a new row, while without them the app still seems to be working?

Comment: **I removed the beginUpdates() and endUpdates() it turns out the app works just fine without them.**
 -- > Without reload data how it can be working fine, You either use beginUpdates() & endUpdates or reload data to update / Animate your tableview

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23260279/335858)

Comment: @AmritTiwari Could you please stop  COPY and PASTE from other's answer such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23260386/3004698

Comment: Option-click on `beginUpdates` and read the pop-up.  It is for grouping multiple inserts or deletes that you want to animate all at once.  There's no need for `begin/endUpdates` for a single insertion or deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate a batch insertion, deletion, and reloading of rows and sections, call the corresponding methods within an animation block defined by successive calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. If you don’t call the insertion, deletion, and reloading methods within this block, row and section indexes may be invalid. Calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` can be nested; all indexes are treated as if there were only the outer update block.

At the conclusion of a block—that is, after `endUpdates` returns—the table view queries its data source and delegate as usual for row and section data. Thus the collection objects backing the table view should be updated to reflect the new or removed rows or sections.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)